# Django-cms CMS plugin with inlines once created inlines dont appear in Edit mode

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a widget 'quick links' I want to add in my footer (In a static placeholder)

I can add the widget and all the inlines. Once created, I can see the inlines in published mode, but the widget is empty in edit mode. Can you help me please?

Models.py

```
class LienFooterPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    langue = models.CharField(max_length=128)

def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
    self.lien_footer = oldinstance.lien_footer.all()

    for lien_footer in oldinstance.lien_footer.all():
        lien_footer.pk = None
        lien_footer.plugin = self
        lien_footer.save()

class LienFooter(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["ordre"]

    lienfooter  = models.ForeignKey(LienFooterPlugin, related_name="lien_footer")
    titre   = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    adresse     = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    ordre       = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

admin.py

```
class LienFooterInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = LienFooter
```

cms_plugins.py

```
class LienFooterAppPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = LienFooterPlugin
    name = u'Liens rapides'
    render_template = "widget/_liens_footer.html"
    inlines = (LienFooterInline,)


    def __init__(self, model=None, admin_site=None):
        super(LienFooterAppPlugin, self).__init__(model=model,
                                                  admin_site=admin_site)
        for inline in self.inlines:
            inline.placeholder = self.placeholder
            inline.page = self.page


    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(LienFooterAppPlugin, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
        items = instance.lien_footer.all()
        context.update({
            'model':instance,
            'placeholder': placeholder,
            'items': items,

        })
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(LienFooterAppPlugin)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: How come you're overriding the `__init__` in your plugin?

Comment: The only question I have found with an Inline CMSPlugin had that. It changes nothing when I take it off.   I think a part of the issue comes from the fact that I am trying to put it in a Staticplaceholder... ?